# How to change the color of the selected code (Vim scheme)?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

How do I change the color of the selected code in Vim?

There are three selection modes, `Visual Line` mode or `Visual Block` mode, and selecting with the mouse).

```
  hi CursorLine guibg=#DDDDDD gui=none
  hi CursorColumn guibg=#EEEEEE gui=none
  hi MatchParen guifg=#f6f3e8 guibg=#857b6f gui=none
  hi Pmenu   guifg=#f6f3e8 guibg=#DDDDDD gui=none
  hi PmenuSel  guifg=#000000 guibg=#DDDDDD gui=none
endif

" General colors
hi Cursor   guifg=NONE    guibg=#656565 gui=none
hi Normal   guifg=#000000 guibg=#FFFFFF gui=none
hi NonText   guifg=#808080 guibg=#FFFFFF gui=none
hi LineNr   guifg=#857b6f guibg=#FFFFFF gui=none
hi StatusLine  guifg=#000000 guibg=#FFFFFF gui=none
hi StatusLineNC guifg=#857b6f guibg=#FFFFFF gui=none
hi VertSplit  guifg=#444444 guibg=#FFFFFF gui=none
hi Folded   guibg=#AAAAAA guifg=#FFFFFF gui=none
hi Title  guifg=#000000 guibg=NONE gui=none
hi Visual  guifg=#000000 guibg=#FFFFFF gui=none
hi SpecialKey guifg=#808080 guibg=#FFFFFF gui=none
```

How do I know which line it is?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Selection color for gvim is set by the following line:

```
hi Visual  guifg=#000000 guibg=#FFFFFF gui=none
```

You can use named color values instead of the #nnnnnn RGB codes.  Your existing line is set for black foreground and white background, just as you observed.

For example, if you want a light blue background with white foreground:

```
hi Visual  guifg=White guibg=LightBlue gui=none
```

Be sure the color file you are editing is in the vim7x/colors directory so both vim and gvim can find it.  Its exact location can vary a bit depending on your OS platform.

Answer (score 40):

**How to set the color of the selected code in vi?**

I'm using VIM 7.3 on Ubuntu and this does it for me within the editor:

```
:syntax on 
:hi Visual term=reverse cterm=reverse guibg=Grey
```

I'm using a colorscheme defined in the /home/youruser/.vim/colors/mycolorscheme.vim file.  I set the command there and the changes take effect when vim starts.

```
syntax on
hi Visual term=reverse cterm=reverse guibg=Grey
```

Comment: I like your use of `reverse` as a syntax aware color theme compatible way

Comment: It changes the text color to white and background to the color of text. But when I have white colored text, the back ground becomes white and the text also white which makes the text invisible. Is there a way to reverse the color of the text as well?

Comment: vim is a fully featured operating system after you get 20 years daily experience using it.  It can do everything.

Answer (score 14):

mu color scheme is molokai, and I found that this configuration is the best for me:

> highlight Visual cterm=bold ctermbg=Blue ctermfg=NONE

[image]

check out my vimrc @https://github.com/reubinoff/myVimrc

Comment: I didn't want a solution where I was going into a color scheme and changing it because if I updated that color scheme it would get overwritten. This was a simple solution that make my zenburn visual selected bg color easier to see (it was dark and dark on dark is not the best contrast)

Comment: This answer works great! It takes what Eric Leschinski shared and makes the text readable. At least for my color scheme. This solution works really well for my MobaXterm sessions using the default terminal color scheme (based off version 22) - "Dark background / Light text".

Answer (score 13):

My highlight

```
:hi Visual cterm=none ctermbg=darkgrey ctermfg=cyan
```

[image]

More xterm colors: https://github.com/guns/xterm-color-table.vim

Answer (score 10):

I just change my color scheme file (`~/.vim/colors/solarized.vim`), and set `'Visual'` to the same value as `'CursorLine'`.

I like the style of `CursorLine` as it is transparent and keep the selected elements's syntax highlight color.

Replace the line that contains `exe "hi! Visual"` with the following line:

```
exe "hi! Visual"     .s:fmt_uopt   .s:fg_none   .s:bg_base02  .s:sp_base1
```

or:

```
:highlight Visual cterm=NONE ctermbg=0 ctermfg=NONE guibg=Grey40
```

Like so:

[image]

Comment: Or add `highlight! link Visual CursorLine` to your vimrc.