# How to change the color of visual selection in Vim?

Tags: vim

I am new to vim and facing a problem where the selected text is very hard to read.[image]

I found this answer [How to change the color of the selected code (Vim scheme)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074068/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-selected-code-vim-scheme) but I am new to Vim, hence cannot understand where to make that change.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the vim screen, press "[: (colon)](http://www.scribendi.com/images/cms/2009-07/Semicolon_and_Colon_photo_FINALIZED.jpg)" and then write

```
hi Visual  guifg=#000000 guibg=#FFFFFF gui=none
```

it should be

```
:hi Visual  guifg=#000000 guibg=#FFFFFF gui=none
```

then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: `guifg` and `guibg` only work for gvim. @Dizzy, experiment with setting `ctermfg` instead. Try values between 1-15

Comment: @progo how to set ctermfg? `:ctermfg` ?

Comment: @Dizzy Try this> hi Visual ctermfg=Yellow ctermbg=NONE cterm=bold,underline